# Point out of curve

Tags: python, manim

I have the secp256k1 elliptic curve and I would like to print a Dot on that curve. However, the dot is out of curve and I can not see why.

- python 3.10.7
- manim 0.17.2

Thanks for any help.

```
from manim import *

class eliptic_curves(MovingCameraScene):
    def secp256k1(self, x):
        return x ** 3 + 7

    def construct(self):
        ax = Axes(
            x_range=[-10, 10]
        )

        # plot the x^3 + 7 = y^2 curve
        graph = ax.plot_implicit_curve(lambda x, y : x ** 3 + 7 - y ** 2, color = BLUE)
        self.add(ax, graph)

        y = np.sqrt(self.secp256k1(1))
        dA = Dot([1, y, 0], color = RED)
        self.add(dA)

with tempconfig({"quality": "medium_quality", "preview": True}):
    scene = eliptic_curves()
    scene.render()
```

[image: Dot out of eliptic curve]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I found a solution. The coordinate system of axes is different from the coordinate system of the Scene (of course). Therefore, I need to use the `ax.coords_to_point` method to put a Dot in the correct position in the `ax` coordinate system.

```
y = np.sqrt(self.secp256k1(1))
dA = Dot(ax.coords_to_point(1, y), color = RED)
```

[image]